# Veryfying javafx app

Tags: java, maven, javafx, deployment

I've created a javafx app and deployed it. I'm running into issues when I try to run it on Windows PC. The message I get is:

> this file does not have a valid digital signature to verify its
>   publisher

[image]

I'm using Maven to package the app, then Launch4js to create .exe then innoSetup to create an installer.

Can anyone advise on a way around this preferably using Maven as I don't know anything about ANT and don't have time to learn it. I need to find a way around this today.

Comment: Have you tried [Wix Toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to sign the application, just like other Windows applications needs to be signed by a key that is trusted by Windows. You can use self-signed certificate, but this will not lead to Windows trusting the signature, you'll have to [purchase a certificate](https://technet.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/cc732597(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_Anchor1) from an authority that has received a signing certificate from Microsoft.

For more information about signing on Windows read the [Introduction to Code Signing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537361(v=vs.85).aspx) of Microsoft.